# How to add a space between ngFor array results

Tags: angular5, ngfor

Can't find an answer to this that works.

Simple *ngFor that returns an array:

```
<ul class="address>
  <li *ngFor="let address of census">
    {{address.occupants}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Seems so easy, BUT results look like:

```
John Smith,John Doe,John Brown
```

Notice the lack of spacing between the results.

This is because "occupants" is an array in my data:

```
  {
    id: 1,
    occupants: ['John Smith', 'John Doe', 'John Brown'],
    address: '5 Johns Street',
  },
```

How do I use *ngFor to output the list of Johns with a space between each entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [join](https://github.com/fknop/angular-pipes/blob/master/docs/array.md#join) pipe from [angular-pipes](https://github.com/fknop/angular-pipes) 
like this:

```
<ul class="address>
 <li *ngFor="let address of census">
   {{address.occupants | join: ' '}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need really in between:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let address of census">
   <li >
     {{address.occupants}}
   </li>{{" "}}
  </ng-container>
```